# How to devolve traits in Plague Inc.: Board game?

Tags: untagged

What happens when you run out of traits slots in Plague Inc.: Board game? You can't evolve new traits anymore? Is there a way to devolve a trait when you want it?

Can't find anything about manual devolve of trait slots in the rules:

https://www.ultraboardgames.com/plague-inc/game-rules.php

P.S. If anyone can give me a link to better rules description I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [these rules](https://s3.amazonaws.com/geekdo-files.com/bgg179406?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22Plague_Inc_TBG_rulebook_v1.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJYFNCT7FKCE4O6TA%2F20220619%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220619T220946Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=d4d4bf1348f021761c4cd7dca6391622288340103b1eb8e17cdab20491e1b90f) that was from the BGG link.

> A player may choose to 'devolve' Trait Card(s) and remove them from
> their Evolution Slide and anytime during their turn. This doesn't
> cost anything or prevent any other action. You must discard the Trait
> Card(s) you devolve.
>
> Note: You do not get DNA Points back when devolving.